# Remove Welcome to in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

How to remove "Welcome to" from header title on front page in Drupal 8

[image]

In drupal 7 you just add in page.tpl.php this part of code:

```
<?php if (!$is_front){
print render($page['content']);
} ?>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In D8 frontpage is a view. To change title of the front page, go to admin/structure/views/view/frontpage, find **Global: Title override** link

[image]

Open it and it will allow to set or remove custom front page title.

Comment: Is it possible to make this text translatable?

Comment: For me, when removing the _Title override_ setting the word _Home_ appears before the site name. Ex. "Home | Dr Taifi". If you want to use only the site name as the front page tile you can modify the *html.html.twig* for your theme and use `<title>{% if not root_path %}{{ head_title.name }}{% else %}{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}{% endif %}</title>` for the title tag.

Answer (score 0):

Default views with url /node we leave as it is.

In page.html.twig we output all blocks except content block:

```
{% if is_front %}
  {{ page.content.breadcrumbs }}
  {{ page.content.page_title }}
  {{ page.content.local_tasks }}
  {{ page.content.help }}
  {{ page.content.local_actions }}
  {#{{ page.content.content }}#} < no content
{% else %}
  {{ page.content }}
{% endif %}
```

page-title.html.twig

```
{% if title %}
    {# nothing #}
{% else %}  {# for other pages #}
    <h1{{ title_attributes.addClass('page-header') }}>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```